# How to animate a view's background in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am targeting level 11+

Its easy to to animate the alpha of the entire view by doing something like

```
view.animate().alpha(0)
```

But this fades the entire view.

I am interested in fading just the background resource/drawable of a view.

How would I do that?

For now I am doing this:

```
view.getBackground().setAlpha(0)
```

But this obviously doesn't animate (fade out) it.

Answer (score 1):

you could use nine old androids (https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids)

```
    ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "backgroundColor", /*Red*/0xFFFF8080, /*Blue*/0xFF8080FF);
colorAnim.setDuration(3000);
colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
colorAnim.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could transform your view in a relative layout and set two separate views inside of it, one for the background (with alpha animation) and one for contents

Comment: thats ugly hack imo. uglier than using a TransitionDrawble. wonder if there is an easier way

Comment: what about extending your view with a custom class and create a custom method where you get the bitmap background,edit its alpha and re-apply to the view 24 times per second?

Comment: yeah thats in essence what the animation framework is doing behind the scene. i will try that (through handler mechanism) approach if there is no elegant alternative solution.

Comment: by the way, i don't think that, in terms of performance, there should be issues with a Relative including a simple View with a sibling Viewgroup...i know it's not so elegant, but it's surely simpler than extending a custom widget. I've noticed a lack of simplest features in android coding, sometimes. But this is simply my opinion